# How can I call a stored procedure from another stored procedure in oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

can I call a stored procedure from another stored procedure in oracle?give me examples.

Comment: Yes............

Comment: yes you can, i think it's better if you try it first before you ask

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two procedures, P_FIRST and P_SECOND and want to call P_SECOND from P_FIRST. The simplest example is this:

```
create or replace procedure p_first as
begin
  p_second;
end;
/
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH @LITTLEFOOT